# The excel file was converted to a Numbers file by AppleScript

Tags: applescript

First, I ran the script code in the script editor, and found that there was an error. The Numbers did not understand the save command, The script command was as follows:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set thisDocument to open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:admin:numbers-FATP.xls"
    tell thisDocument
        save thisDocument in file "Macintosh HD:Users:admin:NumbersTest.numbers"
    end tell
    close thisDocument
end tell
```

And the specific error information was as follows:

```
error "“Numbers” encountered an error：“remove id \"C76B3CB0-D007-46C4-BEB0-9C65D0E65767\"” do not understand “save” information." number -1708 from remove id "C76B3CB0-D007-46C4-BEB0-9C65D0E65767"
```

The point is, sometimes can execute the script code, sometimes can't perform, and it is puzzling, I try to change the computer version and version Numbers, but did not solve the problem, this is why, look forward to your reply, best regards!

I refer to this website: https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/document-save.html

Comment: Have you tried appending `as Numbers` to your `save` command? E.g. `save thisDocument in file "Macintosh HD:Users:admin:NumbersTest.numbers" as Numbers`

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work, I think I should not order problem, because the same command to sometimes can be run, could it be permissions or other external factors, but also does not have any basis.